# Excel file linked to SharePoint list to refresh ever minute

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I have SharePoint 2010 and Office365.
I want an Excel spreadsheet, which has data from a SharePoint list to auto refresh every 1 min.
I tried to follow the procedure from the following [blog](https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/HelpDesk-Update-Excel-Chart-Script.htm)

Here is the VBS code that I'm using:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set wb = xl.WorkBooks.open("\\SPREADSHEET LOCATION\Sharepoint Pivot.xlsx",,TRUE)
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
WScript.Sleep 1000
wb.RefreshAll
wb.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Then I created a task in Task Scheduler to run every minute.
Monitoring the progress in Task Manager, I can see that the file is being opened and it seems to work, but the data is not getting refreshed.
I have a feeling that this is because when the file is opened from SharePoint it's opening with the "Read-Only" message. 
[image]

I thought that the code is taking care of that, but maybe it's not.

I wanted to debug the code by running one step at a time but I dont have access to cscript.exe

Am I doing something wrong here? I've looked around trying to find a solution but everyone seems to have the same code as above.

Thank you

Comment: Don't know about vbs, but look for this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.lockserverfile

Comment: This looks like it will lock the document, not unlock it

Comment: It'll lock it to edit locally. Just take a look if it could help

Comment: What is the bigger picture? What do you want to achieve by refreshing the file with a script? Who consumes the refreshed data? Why not move the refresh part to where the data is actually processed??

Comment: The data from SharePoint gets loaded into Excel sheet. From there I create a Chart and then publish it back to SharePoint as a WebApp. So I just for the Excel sheet to auto refresh

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but found a solution - using .LockServerFile.  See example code:

```
set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=False
set wb = xl.WorkBooks.open("location of excel file goes here")
WScript.Sleep 1000
xl.ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile (only use if location is in Sharepoint to turn off edit mode)
wb.RefreshAll
wb.Save
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=True
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```